# how to save only time not date in database through sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

this query is saving complete date and time. but i want to save only time not date in database. is there any query to do this?

```
update table set current_time=now();
```

Comment: Hint:  `CURTIME()`.

Comment: And if it's an existing datetime column: `CAST(column AS TIME)`

Comment: thank you Gordon Linoff it really works for me. kindly answer this question by this and i will approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column must be set to either DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.

If you use the TIME type then your query would work as expected.

If you are using any other type of column then you could use CURTIME() method or CAST(column AS TIME) as mentioned by other answers, however this would use more space on disk, and make for much slower queries if you use to select, and prevent you from various operators:

e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE current_time<'12:00'`

You can see more information about the different DATE column types here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html

Note that the CURTIME() method is not a standard SQL function, so this would only work on MySql

Answer (score 0):

U can use [CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME())](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx) as the value.

This automates your process without using Current_time=now();

```
INSERT INTO table SET current_time = CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME());
```

You can also use curtime();

```
INSERT INTO table SET current_time = curtime();
```

Credits: Salmaan C